# Material UI list grid on showing up

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to implement material ui grid-list to display images. I tried code given on material ui official page but I am not able to see the grid. This is my code

```
 return (
            <div className={c.container}>
                <AddFileButton
                    openFileUpload={this.openFileUpload.bind(this)}
                    fileUploadIsOpen={this.state.fileUploadIsOpen}
                    openLoading={this.openLoading.bind(this)}
                    loadingIsOpen={this.state.loadingIsOpen}
                    updateImageURLS={this.updateImageURLS}
                    imageURLS={this.state.imageURLS}
                />
                <div style={styles.root}>
                    <GridList style={styles.gridList} cols={2.2}>
                        {this.state.imageURLS.map((x,i) => (
                            <GridTile
                                key={x}
                                                   >
                                <img src={x} />
                            </GridTile>
                        ))}
                    </GridList>
                </div>
            </div>

        )
```

Comment: `cols={2.2}` looks strange to me - it should be an integer value (number of columns). Please try `cols={2}` and see if it works.

Comment: Images are showing up but when the state of imageURLS changes, the grid adds default image icon (html) and not the actual new image to the list. What is the reason?

Comment: That sounds like a problem with your function in which you add the url to the list. Maybe your url is `undefined`? Please `console.log(this.state.imageURLS)` to see if all the urls are correct.